# Crash on rebar3_auto

Tags: erlang, auto, rebar3

When I use `rebar3_auto`, it works only at the compiling, when it is running, I change code in a file to make it load, but I get the error as the following:

```erlang
{undef,[{rebar3_auto,auto,
                     [[<<".erl">>,<<".hrl">>,<<".src">>,<<".lfe">>,
                       <<".config">>,<<".lock">>,<<".c">>,<<".cpp">>,<<".h">>,
                       <<".hpp">>,<<".cc">>]],
                     []}]}
```

After that, changing any file does not effect the automatically compiling nor loading.

Answer (score 0):

`undef` means the the module `rebar3_auto` has not been loaded. [Try to run](https://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#ensure_loaded-1):

```erlang
code:ensure_loaded('rebar3_auto').
```